# Using the right authentication option on App Engine for integrating with Google sign in api

Tags: android, google-app-engine, authentication, oauth, google-signin

I have successfully sent a [Google Sign-in](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth) token ID from my android app to my web application running on GAE. However, the sub value retrieved from Google tokeninfo endpoint (https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=XYZ123) doesn't match the value of the user ID on GAE.The code is below:-

```
 //GAE + Go
 c := appengine.NewContext(r)
 u := user.Current(c)
 log.Println(u.ID) //does not match sub value received from tokeninfo endpoint.
```

I am wondering what went wrong. There are four options for authentication on GAE documentation listed on

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/oauth/

On the web app side that is running on GAE, I am using Users API for identifying user. The user ID retrieved from Users API is different from the sub value received from tokeninfo endpoint when using the same Google account. I thought they should be the same or do I have to use the OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect option stated on the link above?